# How do I view a live execution of a dask graph?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

In several talks about Dask, an animated task graph is shown with nodes coloured red as they are run and blue as they are completed (example: https://youtu.be/RA_2qdipVng?t=23m57s). I couldn't find this functionality in the documentation. Is it easy/possible for a user to produce this visualisation for their tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've done this with a custom callback.  However this isn't fast enough to do live, doing layout and rendering the image with graphviz can be quite slow:

https://gist.github.com/mrocklin/5b7bf78621496697fa3001462e1910ae

Comment: Cool, thanks! For long-running (>1s) tasks this should be close to live anyway, no? Also, from a quick skim of your code, it looks like you're re-drawing the whole graph each time, while the Python graphviz docs suggest that you can style nodes after graph creation: http://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#styling Not sure yet if that's a significant speedup.

Comment: If you can make this fast we'd love to have it as a plugin